# access variable from inside new object definition

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using prototypejs. Code is:

```
var someVariable;
new Ajax.Request('blah.php', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { username: $('username').value, password: $('password').value },
        onComplete: function(response) {
            //access someVariable here?
        }
```

How do I acess someVariable from where I have mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You just refer to it by name as you normally would. In your code, the function you're specifying for `onComplete` is a *closure* over the context in which `someVariable` is defined, and so it has an enduring reference to that variable.

```
var someVariable;
new Ajax.Request('blah.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: { username: $('username').value, password: $('password').value },
    onComplete: function(response) {
        someVariable = /* some value */;
    }
```

More about closures: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Note that this is even true when you're doing this in a function that has since returned:

```
function doSomeAjax() {
    var someVariable;
    new Ajax.Request('blah.php', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { username: $('username').value, password: $('password').value },
        onComplete: function(response) {
            someVariable = /* some value */;
        }
    });
}
```

Since the ajax call is asynchronous, `doSomeAjax` will return before your `onComplete` function is called. That's perfectly fine, `someVariable` will still be there, because there's still something (your `onComplete` function) that refers to the context in which they were defined, and so that context is kept in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your variable `someVariable` is in the same level or context (within a closure or a function) you can just use inside the anonymous function in the `onComplete` callback. Not sure what you plan with it but you can assign value to it or use it as an assignment to another variable upon receiving the response.